# How to make Regex re.search(r"\s", word) not consider \n as whitespace?

Tags: python, regex

After searching online I realized that  re.search(r"\s", word) considers "\n" as whitespace if it is in the word. I am parsing data of a large JSON file and almost all the words have \n in them but I actually just want to neglect that \n and actually look for spaces. For e.g some words in that JSON look like "\nfibonacci" and "\nfibonnaci sequence" and "fibonaccifinal". In all those cases only the second word has an actual space which is what I am trying to parse out but with my code this is not happening since \n is considered a whitespace. How do I solve it?

```
import re

def check_word(word):
    res = bool(re.search(r"\s", word))
    if res is True:
        print("String contains spaces")
    else:
        print("String has no space")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    word = '\nFibonacci'
    check_word(word)
```

Comment: Use just a space character instead of `\s`?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead: `(?!\n)\s`

Comment: `if res is True:` —> `if res:`, and the `bool()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks. I feel so stupid now asking this question

Comment: What about a tab `\t`? That's also a legit white space :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CertainPerformance I realized that the answer to my question is as easy as adding a space in the search method.

```
import re

def check_word(word):
    res = bool(re.search(r" ", word))
    if res is True:
        print("String contains spaces")
    else:
        print("String has no space")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    word = '\nFibonacci'
    check_word(word)
```